# picasso and glide are not loading the image from web

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

picasso and glide are not loading the image from web. Below is the jave and xml. First i use picasso which is commented out now, then i use the glide library, but the problem is same. nothing appears on screen. if i ad image source from assets it appears on preview of android studio but i want to load image from web and show it in the image view. please correct my mistake if any..? Thanks.

JAVA:

```
ImageView imageBanner1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBanner1);
    ImageView imageBanne2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBanner2);

    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://example.com/appBanner1.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(imageBannerl);
    /*Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("http://example.com/appBanner1.jpg")
            .skipMemoryCache()
            .into(imageBannerl);*/
    imageBanner1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent inttv=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Play.class);
            inttv.putExtra("url","http://example.com");
            startActivity(inttv);
        }
    });
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://example.com/appBanner2.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .into(imageBanner2);
    /*Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("http://example.com/appBanner2.jpg")
            .skipMemoryCache()
            .into(imageBanner2);*/

    imageBannerAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent imageBannerBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
            startActivity(imageBannerBrowserIntent);
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageBannerLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageBanner1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/app_background" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageBanner2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/app_background" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've just hit the link you're using and they're broken

Comment: Make sure you have provided internet access in manifest and the image urls are valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```

I think you need to check your ImageView variable name.
You have used ImageView imageBanner1 and ImageView imageBanne2 as variable name but never used it.Instead you have used imageBannerChannel and imageBannerAd as variable name. Once Check your code again. And make sure your url is fine.